Why are my tensorflow gradients None when using tf.python.ops.gradients?
I am struggling with tensorflow gradients. I am using a custom second order optimizer where I need to compute hessians. The library I have chosen uses tf.python.ops.gradients instead of the standard tape.gradients(...). Running the below script raises a value error (gradients are None):
import numpy as np

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.keras.optimizer_v2 import optimizer_v2
from tensorflow.python.keras import backend
from tensorflow.python.ops import gradients
from tensorflow.python.util import nest


class SecondOrderOptimizer(optimizer_v2.OptimizerV2):
    _HAS_AGGREGATE_GRAD = True
    def __init__(self, name='SecondOrderOpt', **kwargs):
        super(SecondOrderOptimizer, self).__init__(name, **kwargs)

    def get_gradients_hessian(self, loss, params):
        params = nest.flatten(params)
        with backend.get_graph().as_default(), backend.name_scope(self._name+"/gradients"):
            grads = gradients.gradients(loss, params)
            for grad, param in zip(grads, params):
                if grad is None:
                    raise ValueError("Variable {} has `None` for gradient. ".format(param))

np.random.seed(42)
X_train = np.linspace(-1, 1, 100).reshape(-1, 1)
y_train = X_train**2 + np.random.normal(0, 0.05, (100, 1))

X_train = tf.Variable(X_train, dtype=tf.float32)
y_train = tf.Variable(y_train, dtype=tf.float32)

class SimpleNN(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SimpleNN, self).__init__()
        self.hidden = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='relu')
        self.output_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='linear')
        
    def call(self, x):
        x = self.hidden(x)
        return self.output_layer(x)

model = SimpleNN()
loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()
optimizer = SecondOrderOptimizer()

def train_step(model, X, y, optimizer):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        # loss = tf.reduce_sum((y - X**2)**2)
        loss = loss_fn(y, model(X, training=True))

    grads, Hessian = optimizer.get_gradients_hessian(loss, model.trainable_weights)
    #optimizer.apply_gradients_hessian(zip(grads, Hessian, model.trainable_weights)) # omitted 
    
    return loss

for epoch in range(100):
    loss = train_step(model, X_train, y_train, optimizer)

I am using python 3.10 with tensorflow 2.15.
This scripts eliminates the possibilities posted in tensorflow's "Cases where gradient returns None" documentation. The original package creators are unresponsive.

You should not use anything from tf.python as it's not part of the public API. There is tf.gradients but you need to read the docs to use it correctly (only works in graph mode).
